# XPATH: multiple negations in for-each

Tags: xslt, xpath, foreach

I have the following simplified XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<MATMAS05>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <E1MARAM SEGMENT="1">
        <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
        <MATNR>000000000000401436</MATNR>
        <E1MARCM SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
            <WERKS>A120</WERKS>
            <MMSTA>01</MMSTA>
        </E1MARCM>
        <E1MVKEM SEGMENT="1">
            <VKORG>0120</VKORG>
            <VMSTA>04</VMSTA>
        </E1MVKEM>
    </E1MARAM>
</IDOC>
</MATMAS05>
```

If `<WERKS>=A120` and `<MMSTA> is NOT '01' or '02' or '03'` OR if `<VKORG>=0120` and `<VMSTA> is NOT '01' or '02' or '03'` then the `<MATNR>` should be mapped to the target XML.

I came up with the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each
        select="IDOC[(E1MARAM/E1MVKEM[VKORG='0120'][not(VMSTA='01' or VMSTA='02' or VMSTA='03')])
            or (E1MARAM/E1MARCM[WERKS = 'A120'][not(MMSTA='01' or MMSTA='02' or MMSTA='03')])]">
        <Item>
            <ITEM_CODE>
                <xsl:value-of select="E1MARAM/MATNR"/>
            </ITEM_CODE>
        </Item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But if I apply that XSLT I get the following unwanted output (because `<MMSTA>='01'`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item>
<ITEM_CODE>000000000000401436</ITEM_CODE>
</Item>
```

How can I solve this? I have tried around with that XPATH expression but I can't get the wanted result. What am I doing wrong in my XPATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
//IDOC[(E1MARAM/E1MVKEM[VKORG='0120' and not(VMSTA='01' or VMSTA='02' or VMSTA='03')]) or (E1MARAM/E1MARCM[WERKS='A120' and not(MMSTA='01' or MMSTA='02' or MMSTA='03')])]
```

I tried yours as well, and it works if you add the root to IDOC, since MATMAS05 is the actual root:

```
//IDOC[(E1MARAM/E1MVKEM[VKORG='0120'][not(VMSTA='01' or VMSTA='02' or VMSTA='03')])             or (E1MARAM/E1MARCM[WERKS = 'A120'][not(MMSTA='01' or MMSTA='02' or MMSTA='03')])]
```

Comment: thank you jdwilemo, it is similar to Aravin's solution and I prefer yours because I add the root only once +1

Answer (score 1):

`not(MMSTA='01' or MMSTA='02' or MMSTA='03')` returns true always because .. `MMSTA` is not child of `IDOC`  so you should use `//MMSTA`

Comment: Thank you Aravin, it works well; it is similar to jdwilemo's solution with the root node; lesson learnt ;-) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output  method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each
        select="IDOC[(E1MARAM/E1MARCM/WERKS/text() = 'A120' 
and descendant::MMSTA/text() != '01' 
and descendant::MMSTA/text() != '02' 
and descendant::MMSTA/text() != '03')
or (E1MARAM/E1MVKEM/VKORG/text() = '120' 
and descendant::VMSTA/text() != '01'
and descendant::VMSTA/text() != '02'
and descendant::VMSTA/text() != '03')]">
        <Item>
            <ITEM_CODE>
                <xsl:value-of select="E1MARAM/MATNR"/>
            </ITEM_CODE>
        </Item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Baran, you also implicate the relation to the root node. That was my big mistake in the beginning. I did go with the other solution though because the expression is shorter; still +1